# ¿Cómo poner un botón encima de un Canva si estoy en una pestaña Toplevel?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Cuando creó los botones con "tk.Button"  en "def AWP():" no aparecen en la ventana creada por el Toplevel del def. pero si saco el Canvas (que coloca el Background) , los botones aparecen. La verdad es muy raro, ya que, el Background del root está creado con un Canvas y no hay ningún problema con el botón salir. La verdad soy bastante nuevo en esto y si me pudieran ayudar estaría totalmente agradecido.

Gracias por adelantado.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image    

#Defs Armas y salir    
def AWP():
    ventana_awp = Toplevel()
    ventana_awp.geometry("480x320")
    ventana_awp.iconbitmap('img/csgo.ico')
    ventana_awp.title("AWP")


    canvas=Canvas(ventana_awp, width=480,height=320)
    image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("D:\\rserp\\0\\Fotos stock presentaciones\\back.png"))
    canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image=image)
    canvas.pack()

    button1 = tk.Button(ventana_awp,text="Exit")
    button1.pack(pady=20)

    ventana_awp.mainloop()

def mensaje():
    answer=messagebox.askyesno("Salir", "    ¿Desea Salir?")
    if(answer):
        root.destroy()
def no_configurado():
    messagebox.showinfo("( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)", "Botón de lujo, no tiene ninguna función ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Catalogo Armas CSGO")
root.iconbitmap('img/csgo.ico')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.geometry("480x320")

#Imagen de fondo

canvas=Canvas(root, width=480,height=320)
image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("D:\\rserp\\0\\Fotos stock presentaciones\\unnamed.png"))
canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image=image)
canvas.pack()


mi_menu = tk.Menu(root)
armas_counter=tk.Menu(mi_menu, tearoff=0)
armas_terrorist=tk.Menu(mi_menu, tearoff=0)

#Lista Armas CT
armas_counter.add_command(label='AWP', command=AWP)
armas_counter.config(fg='#0091ff')

#lista Armas TT
armas_terrorist.config(fg='#1b8500')

#Cascade's
mi_menu.add_cascade(label='Armas Counter-Terrorist', menu=armas_counter)
mi_menu.add_cascade(label='Armas Terrorist', menu=armas_terrorist)

#Botones
botonsalir = Button(root, text="SALIR", command=mensaje)
botonsalir.place(x=210,y=200)
botonsalir.config(font=("Arial", 13, "bold"), fg="#DAD5D6", bg="#D32214")   

root.config(menu=mi_menu)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solución

Lo que está pasando en realidad es que los botones se crean debajo del canvas (puedes comprobarlo cambiando el tamaño de la ventana, verás que los botones aparecen).

Hay una solución al problema, pero implica que no podrás usar pack ni grid. Tendrás que usar coordenadas para ubicar los widgets, perdiéndote así facilidades de grid y pack :c

Los canvas tienen un método que te permite ubicar widgets dentro de ellos. Este método se llama [create_window](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_window.html). Los argumentos que nos van a importar son los siguientes:

- `x` (primer argumento) la ubicación del widget en el eje x
- `y` (segundo argumento) la ubicación del widget en el eje y
- `anchor` que parte del widget será ubicada en x e y. Por ejemplo anchor="nw" ubica la parte noroeste del widget en x e y. Por default, este argumento es "center".
- `window` el widget a ubicar dentro del canvas.

---

A continuación, presento un código de prueba para demostrar como funciona. Se que utilizo Tk en lugar de Toplevel, pero creeme que la solución también sirve para toplevels:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image    

v = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(v)

fondo = PhotoImage(file="imagen.png")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=fondo)

boton = Button(canvas, text="botón de prueba")
canvas.create_window(100, 100, anchor="nw", window=boton)

canvas.pack()

v.mainloop()
```

En mi opinión, funcionar funciona, pero se te complicarán un poco las cosas. Te recomiendo usar un fondo de un solo color (evitando así usar un canvas, ya que establecerle un fondo de un solo color a las ventanas y los widgets es sencillo, no requiere ningún sacrificio y no requiere usar canvas).

#### Bonus: Unos consejos

A continuación, voy a dar mi perspectiva sobre como podrías mejorar tu código:

**1- Forma de importar Tkinter**

En esta sección:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

Importas dos veces Tkinter de dos formas diferentes. Te recomiendo elegir una forma. Tal y como está hecho tu código para hacer menos cambios extra podrías usar `from tkinter import *`, pero oí que es una forma no recomendada. En ese caso podrías usar `import tkinter as tk`.

Si haces el ultimo cambio, tendrás que agregarle el prefijo tk. a todos comandos de tkinter, como los que usas para crear widgets. Por ejemplo:

```
canvas=Canvas(root, width=480,height=320)
```

Cambiarla por

```
canvas=tk.Canvas(root, width=480,height=320)
```

Pero si aplicas lo otro, tendrás que eliminar dicho prefijo, por ejemplo cambiar esto:

```
mi_menu = tk.Menu(root)
```

Por esto:

```
mi_menu = Menu(root)
```

**2- Establecer color del texto de un menú sin usar config**

Puedes configurar el color del texto de un menú en el momento en el que lo creas. No es necesario usar config luego. Por ejemplo, puedes quitar esta linea `armas_counter.config(fg='#0091ff')` y cambiar esta `armas_counter=tk.Menu(mi_menu, tearoff=0)` por esta `armas_counter=tk.Menu(mi_menu, tearoff=0, fg='#0091ff')`:

Comment: Solo una observación a las recomendaciones que haces respecto de la forma de importar tkinter. Según he leído, la forma correcta es con estas dos líneas:
"from tkinter import *", y 
"from tkinter import ttk". 
La explicación que da es esta:
"These two lines tell Python that our program needs two modules. The first, tkinter, is the standard binding to Tk. When imported, it loads the Tk library on your system. The second, ttk, is a submodule of tkinter. It implements Python's binding to the newer "themed widgets" that were added to Tk in 8.5."